# Error while trying to upload a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a file upload control and a button:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="venfileupld" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="venupld1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="venupld1_Click" />
```

In the button click event I am doing this:

```
string name = venfileupld.PostedFile.FileName;

    string filepath = Server.MapPath("upload_excel/") + name;
    venfileupld.PostedFile.SaveAs(filepath);

 writetoven();
```

But it's giving me an error.

My first question is why I am getting an error on the line:

```
string name = venfileupld.PostedFile.FileName;
```

It's giving null that the uploader doesn't have any file.

And the second question is how I get the file that I can pass on the function named:

```
 writetoven();
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Ajx with an UpdatePanel?

Comment: yes i am using ajax and updatepanel

Comment: @ArindamDas - So post that code?

Comment: string name = venfileupld.PostedFile.FileName; this line gives wrong file name which includes the path as well so when you concatenate it with file path it becomes invalid path. thats why you were getting error on this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are you using ASP.NET Ajx with an UpdatePanel?
>   ...
>   yes i am using ajax and updatepanel

[FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) doesn't work inside of an `UpdatePanel`. You must use an [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx) from the [ASPNET AJAX control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/).

Look here for more details: http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.de/2009/02/file-upload-not-working-with-update.html

You should handle the `UploadedComplete` event of the `AsyncFileUpload` control:

```
private static List<string> allowedExtensions = new List<string>(new string[] {
".xls",
".xlsx"
});

protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.state == AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadState.Success) {
        string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(e.filename);
        if (allowedExtensions.Contains(fileExt)) {
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.filename);
            string dir = Server.MapPath("upload_excel/");
            string path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
            AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
            AsyncFileUpload1.FileContent.Close();
        } else {
            // wrong extension
        }
    } else {
        // log and show error
    }
}
```

Comment: ok then should i use that control's event or should i stick to my button_click event?

Comment: and should i use ajaxfileupload or asyncfileupload ?

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1830951.aspx/1 Do you need to support multi file upload? Then use `ajaxfileupload` otherwise `asyncfileupload`.

Comment: ok thanks that uploaded the file but how i am going to get the file on `uploadbtn_click` event bcoz i need to reed it.. ?

Comment: You should handle the `UploadedComplete` event of the `AsyncFileUpload` control.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check upload control has file by its property "HasFile"  before assign a file name to variable "name"  you can see best example from following link :
http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2008/10/fileupload-control-example.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are using `enctype=multipart/form-data` in your form tag. That will allow file upload controls to be posted to asp.net server and you will start receiving data in `venfileupld.PostedFile` object and other properties.

Use `venfileupld.HasFile` and `venfileupld.ContentLength` properties to make sure file is uploaded and is not 0kb.

-- update --

Based on the fact that you are using update panel, you can try adding a postback trigger like

```
 <Triggers>
  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadControlId" />
 </Triggers>
```

----- end of update ----

Add more details if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: no that didn't solve .. i am using ajax and updatepanel ... is that a problem?? then what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

Code behind:

```
protected void venupld1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = venfileupld.FileName;
        string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/upload_excel/") + name;
        venfileupld.PostedFile.SaveAs(filepath);
     }
```

Code inline:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"  UpdateMode="conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="venfileupld" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="venupld1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="venupld1_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="venupld1" />
    </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope this helps.